# where is the direction for the orientation of component?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I made a simple robot and read the orientation of robot's head, but I do not know where is the direction of orientation = 0, How I can check where is the direction of orientation = 0. is the orientation based on the axis, or something else? if based on the axis, how is the axis (or how can I see the robot orientation on the axis)? Take the human for a simple example, if you know your orientation = 0, but where is my direction for orientation = 0, forward, left, right or some angle else?

In my understanding, draw a line in orientation = 0 is a good way to fix the question, but I really have no idea how to draw a line in gazebo. looking forward to the answers.

I am hurry to know the answer to my experiment, Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18570/where-is-the-direction-for-the-orientation-of-component?/) by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-02-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2018-02-20**:
this is mean, where is the direction if orientation = 0. is it in the direction of +x axis, -x axis, -y axis or y axis?

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2018-02-20**:
is anybody has answer for this question? in my understanding (I have run a small experiment to check this problem, but I think it is not enough to fix the question), orientation = 0 is the direction in +x axis, but I am sure if it is right. can you give me some ideas?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-02-20**:
Please don't post an answer with more questions, either update the existing question or post a new one, if the question is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I suggest you right-click your model and choose `View->Transparent` and then `View->Link Frame`. You'll then see how your component is oriented in the world.

For example, the box below has a zero orientation with respect to the world in all 3 axes (X/Y/Z):

[image: image description]

Good luck with your experiment.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2018-02-21**:
Thanks! I have checked like you did, But I am not sure where is the zero orientation? the orientation is a rotation around z axis, but where is the start (zero orientation), we can not fix this question with this way. In my understanding, the start (zero orientation) is from the positive x axis, but I can not sure it is right. do you have some more powerful keys? the above answer is helpful to understand my question, could you go to see the above answer. Thanks again!

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-02-21**:
The orientation is in 3 dimensions. A zero orientation means that all of the object's axes (X, Y and Z) are aligned with the world's X, Y and Z axes.

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2018-02-22**:
yes, you are right, I am sorry I did not give a specific question. For my question, zero orientation is for zero yaw. where is the start (zero Yaw)? For my understand, the start (zero Yaw) is from positive x axis, is this right, or ...?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-02-22**:
Got it. Sure, yaw is the angle from the world's +X to your model's +X, counterclockwise if looked from above.

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2018-02-24**:
perfect, Thanks! how can I check this? do we have some tutorial or document to see? or anyway else?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-02-24**:
Gazebo uses right-handed coordinates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule#Coordinates

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2018-02-25**:
thanks! and can you help to answer this question? http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18360/how-can-i-reset-the-robot-to-the-same-situations-in-the-beginning-of-each-running/

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-02-25**:
It looks like I've answered it a few weeks ago ;) Leave a comment there if you need more help

**Comment by [dagiopia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8106/dagiopia/) on 2019-02-28**:
@chapulina is there a way to obtain a vector indicating the relative coordinate orientation of the model with respect to the world in the gazebo C++ api or does one have to do a transformation using the pitch, roll  and yaw params from WorldPose in order to get that vector?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2019-02-28**:
I'm not sure I understand the question, sounds like you're interested in the model's XYZ position in the world? I think it's best you start a new question for this.

**Comment by [dagiopia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8106/dagiopia/) on 2019-03-01**:
ok thanks! here's my question http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22051/link-local-coordinate-frame/